# ASP.NET Core 6 - generic Startup setup in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have multiple ASP.NET Core 6 Web API projects. Each api is used by the same client app.

In each API, I had to manually setup CORS with exactly the same config.

I want to avoid code duplication by creating a small dedicated project called `CorsSetup`.

In this project, I want a simple method to call, and it will make all the setup.

Here my issue :

Normally, CORS setup is done in two steps in `Startup.cs`:

- in `ConfigureServices`, there's a line `services.AddCors(.....)`
- and in the `Configure` method, there's a call `app.UseCors(mycors);`

Is it possible in another project/class to make all this setup in only one method?

Here's a code example :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace Company.CorsTool;

public static class ServiceExtension
{
    public static string allowSpecificOriginsName = "AllowCors";
    
    public static string[] allowedDomainProd = new string[] {  "http://example.com" };

    public static string[] allowedDomainDebug = new string[] { "https://prodexample.com" };
    
    public static void AddCompanyCors(this IServiceCollection services, bool isDev = false)
    {
        services.AddCors(
            options => options.AddPolicy(allowSpecificOriginsName,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .WithOrigins(isDev ? allowedDomainDebug.Concat(allowedDomainProd).ToArray() : allowedDomainProd)
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                })
        );
    }

    public static void UseCompanyCors(this IApplicationBuilder app, bool isDev = false)
    {
        app.UseCors(allowSpecificOriginsName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest why do you have multiple api projects? could you not achieve the same result with multiple controllers handling the endpoints in one project? it would be easier then to implement the shared CORS config...just a thought

Comment: Multiple api's for multiple different projects, features, type of deployment, network ,architecture and many reasons. like soa architecture.